# Where can I buy a replacement MagSafe female chip for my MacBook Pro?

Tags: charging, magsafe, hardware

I am trying to find a replacement charging chip for my MacBook pro 5.5 (mid 2009).  I have looked on eBay and can't find them.  Does anyone know of a site that sells parts like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-MagSafe-DC-In-Board/IF163-011, it looks to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Holy mother of the lord.  $50...  Does anyone know where I can find it cheaper than that?

Comment: Sorry mate, I looked around and couldn't find anything. Plus, iFixit is a reputable vendor, that must be worth something.